# Unable to open the Performance Logs and Alerts configuration

Tags: perfmon

I'm trying to set up some perfmon logging on our server and I get this message in the event log

"Unable to open the Performance Logs and Alerts configuration. This configuration is initialized when you use the Performance Logs and Alerts Management Console snapin to create a Log or Alert session."

Any ideas? Googling hasn't turned up anything useful so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah ha!

This fixed it for me

http://forums.techarena.in/windows-server-help/778076.htm

Specifically

"Try changing the log on properties of the Performance Logs and Alerts
service to use the Local Service Account. This fixed the issue when I
was having this same error."